# How do I set the mask and values parameters for SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to use this API call in my app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdialogdpichangebehavior

```
BOOL SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior(
  HWND                        hDlg,
  DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS mask,
  DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS values
);

typedef enum DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS {
  DDC_DEFAULT                   ,
  DDC_DISABLE_ALL               ,
  DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE            ,
  DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT
} ;
```

The documentation says that `mask` is "a mask specifying the subset of flags to be changed." and `values` is "the desired value to be set for the specified subset of flags." In the remarks it says "For extensibility, DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS was modeled as a set of bit-flags representing separate behaviors. This function follows the typical two-parameter approach to setting flags, where a mask specifies the subset of the flags to be changed."

I can't find any code samples that show how this method is actually called. If the function just had a single `flags` parameter it would make sense to me, but I don't know how to handle it with these two `mask` and `values` params.

Comment: *"If the function just had a single `flags` parameter it would make sense to me"* - How would that hypothetical function distinguish between a bit that should be reset, and a bit that should not be change altogether? Passing a single value (like `0`) wouldn't suffice. You need a mask to disambiguate between those operations.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure why I would need to distinguish between a bit that should be reset and a bit that should not be changed in this context. I just want to explicitly set the behavior of a form in my app and I'm not concerned with whatever it was set to before. Or maybe I am, I don't know - that's why I said "it would make sense to me" and not "it would be better".

Comment: It is brand-new, samples are going to take a while, even the docs are buggy.  Probably what is throwing you off, the enum is not actually declared that way.  They have true bitmask values, respectively 0, 1, 2 and 4.

Comment: `I just want to explicitly set the behavior of a form in my app and I'm not concerned with whatever it was set to before` In this case set `mask = DDC_DEFAULT | DDC_DISABLE_ALL | DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT` and you have desired behavior.

Comment: The mask parameter is not a necessity, it's a convenience. In fact, many "setter" APIs don't have a mask parameter. One can achieve the same effect by first calling the "getter" API, applying bitwise operations to the result and finally call the "setter" API. E. g. `SetSomething((GetSomething() & ~mask) | (values & mask))`.

Comment: @HansPassant I noticed that you know about Qt. Do you happen to know what include statement I need in order to be able to call SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior? I already had `#include <windows.h>` in order to call `SetWindowPos`, but neither that nor `#include <winuser.h>` seem to include `SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior`.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not in control of our build server, but I think we're building to support Windows 8 and SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior appears to be Windows 10 only, so that may be my problem.

Comment: It requires Windows 10, version 1703 or newer and at least Windows SDK 10 v1703. If you have to support earlier Windows versions, dynamically obtain function address with `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 6):

There is bug in documentation. `DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS` definition from `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um\winuser.h`:

```
typedef enum DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS {
    DDC_DEFAULT                     = 0x0000,
    DDC_DISABLE_ALL                 = 0x0001,
    DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE              = 0x0002,
    DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT    = 0x0004,
} DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS;
```

Aside from `DDC_DEFAULT` these are simple bitflags that could be ored with |.

```
SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior(
    hwnd,
    DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT,
    DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT );
```

Essentially this works as:

```
flags = ( flags & ~mask ) | ( values & mask );
```

If `mask` bit is equal 0 it preserves old bit value in `flags`, if `mask` bit is equal 1 `flags` bit is changed according to bit in `values`.

[image: changing flags depending on mask and values]

To set `flag` bit you set bit in both `mask` and `values`. To clear you set bit in `mask` but don't set it in `values`.

```
// Sets DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE bit
SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior( hwnd, DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE, DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE );
// Clears DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE bit
SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior( hwnd, DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE, 0 );
// Sets DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT and clears DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE
SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior(
    hwnd,
    DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT,
    DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT );
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Btw, what's the point to use both `values` and `mask`? Just using correct `values` would be enough information. Also, in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvitemw) structure, it seems like there is only `mask` and no `values`. Could you explain why?

Comment: This is how you can change only selected bits, Without mask you would have to first get all flags, manipulate them and finally call seting function.

Answer (score 1):

mask: set only values you want to change, for example: `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT`.

values: contains new values. For example, if values = 0, `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE` and `DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT` will be set to 0, all other values remain unchanged. If values = `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE` with the same mask, `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE` will be set to 1, and `DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT` to 0.

Another example. If you want to enable `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE`, use mask = `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE`, values `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE`. If you want to disable `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE`, use mask `DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE` and values 0.

If this helps, the function pseudo-code is:

```
for each flag from enum DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS
{
    if flag is set in mask
    {
       set flag value from values
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to make sure that DDC_DEFAULT (and only DDC_DEFAULT) was set, I would call it once with mask = DDC_DEFAULT and values = 1 and then call it a second time with mask = DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DDC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT and values = 0? I'll try this, but I don't understand why the third param would be `values` (plural) instead of `value`.

Comment: Or you're saying not values = 1 but values = DDC_DEFAULT etc.? I'm really confused by this way of setting flags. The doc says "the typical two-parameter approach to setting flags" but I couldn't find any examples of this anywhere. Is there anything that explains this approach in a straightforward way?

Comment: Third param is called `values` because it may contain several values, maximal 4 in this case. If you want to set all values in one call, use mask = `DDC_DEFAULT | DDC_DISABLE_ALL | DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT`. In this case new flags will be as defined in the `values` parameter.

Comment: You want to to make sure that DDC_DEFAULT is set. mask =  DDC_DEFAULT, values = DDC_DEFAULT.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting this at all. Would you mind posting a complete example or two in your answer? I would normally just try this out quickly with some experimentation, but I'm stuck in a process where I can only build changes on my server (a 30 minute process) and deploy to my test laptop.

Comment: So, if I wanted `DDC_DEFAULT` to be set (and all other flags to not be set) I would use mask = DDC_DEFAULT | DDC_DISABLE_ALL | DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT and values = DDC_DEFAULT ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Another way to understand this: use mask = `DDC_DEFAULT | DDC_DISABLE_ALL | DDC_DISABLE_RESIZE | DC_DISABLE_CONTROL_RELAYOUT` and think that this parameter doesn't exist :)